# how to remove #! from the urls of mean js application?

Tags: node.js, meanjs

In mean js deep linking is enabled on default.how to remove #! in url of the mean js application ? i have tried using removing the following line in public/application.js.

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
```

and adding the following line to public/application.js.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

but when I type the url http://localhost:3000/articles to access the article list view it shows the endpoint with articles json object array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

anyway I found the answer for my question. add

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

to the config/application.js.and add

```
 <base href="/">
```

to app/views/layout.server.view.html.

and add

```
var core = require('../app/controllers/core.server.controller');
app.get('/*', core.index);
```

to the express.js file.